# Bad permalinks adding "%20%E2%80%8E"

Tags: character, permalinks

Can anybody help me on this issue? It's very important to my site.

Some (although not all) of my permalinks won't work. Some work perfectly and some are having variants of this "%20%E2%80%8E" added to the end of them, which obviously is giving me the 404 message.

I've tried deactivating plug ins but had no difference and obviously as some work, it is unlikely to be that. I have also checked for hidden characters but cannot seem to find any.

Can anybody think of a viable reason/solution for this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c# .net then before open the url just encode it.

```
ReplacedString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(YourString);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using wordpress. could this still apply? if so where would I add the string? into the processor or literally in front of the link?